# XML file appears to be randomly corrupting and can't figure it out

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml file being used on our wordpress site that gets updated with the post ID every time someone views a post.

The file structure looks like this…

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <posts>
     <refresh>
        <datetime>2013-01-04 08:48:21</datetime>
     </refresh>
     <post id="21931">
        <postviews>5</postviews>
     </post>
     <post id="25420">
        <postviews>18</postviews>
     </post>
     <post id="17770">
        <postviews>25</postviews>
     </post>
     <post id="24925">
        <postviews>4</postviews>
     </post>
  </posts>
```

Every time someone view a post if the post ID isn't in the file it adds a new node or if it exists it updates the current value by 1.

The problem I have, is that sometimes the file isn't being written to correctly, and it ends up being corrupted and looking like the following (the error is always at the bottom of the file)…

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <posts>
     <refresh>
        <datetime>2013-01-04 08:48:21</datetime>
     </refresh>
     <post id="21931">
        <postviews>5</postviews>
     </post>
     <post id="25420">
        <postviews>18</postviews>
     </post>
     <post id="17770">
        <postviews>25</postviews>
     </post>
   </posts>         
   id="24925">
        <postviews>4</postviews>
     </post>
  </posts>
```

I have spoken to our hosting company and the problem isn't showing up as a server error. Could it be a problem with my script that writes to the XML file? The script I have written is below…

```
<?php

 // echo get_the_ID();

if($post->post_status != "publish" || is_user_logged_in()) { 

    //Get the wordpress postID
$postID = get_the_ID();

$postData = get_post($postID);  

// Don't do anything if the post isn't published or being viewed by logged in users - will give a false impression
// echo $postID.'<br />'.$postData->post_title.'<br />'.$postData->post_date_gmt.'<br />';

} else { 

//Get the wordpress postID
$postID = get_the_ID();

$postData = get_post($postID);  

// echo $postID.'<br />'.$postData->post_title.'<br />'.$postData->post_date_gmt.'<br />';

$xmlFile = get_stylesheet_directory().'/most-read/most-read-posts.xml';

// load the document
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);


// Get the server time
$serverTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Is their a refresh node with an entry of datetime?
$refreshNodeExists = $xml->xpath("//refresh");

// Count it if 
$countrefreshNodeExists = count($refreshNodeExists);

// If it does exists
if($countrefreshNodeExists != 0) { // If the ID is already in the file

    $xmlRefresh = $xml->refresh->datetime;

    // echo 'Refresh time is already set<br /><br />';

} else {

    // echo 'Refresh time is not set<br /><br />';

    $refreshNode = $xml->addChild('refresh');

    $refreshNode->addChild('datetime', $serverTime);

}

// Check the time elapsed between the server time and the refreshNode

// Get and format the refreshNode
$to_time = strtotime($xmlRefresh);

// Get and format the server time
$from_time = strtotime($serverTime);

// Calculate the time elapsed
$refreshTimeElapsed = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);

// How long do we want to have between file refreshing - in minutes?
$refreshInterval = 120;

// Check if the time elapsed is more or less than $refreshInterval
if ($refreshTimeElapsed > $refreshInterval) {

    // FOR TESTING ONLY - Show the time elapsed
    // echo 'Ooops were over the refresh limit. It\'s currently at: '.$refreshTimeElapsed.' minutes.<br /><br />';

    $fh = fopen($xmlFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

    $stringData = '<?xml version="1.0"?><posts><refresh><datetime>'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'</datetime></refresh></posts>';

    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    fclose($fh);

                /*$test = $xml->xpath("//post");

                if (!empty($test)) {

                    echo 'Houston, we have posts';

                } else {

                    echo 'That\'s a negative Houston, we have no posts here';

                }*/

    // Reset the datetime node with the current datetime to start the refresh loop again.
    $xml->refresh->datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

} else { // Don't need to do anything here really

    // FOR TESTING ONLY - show how much time has elapsed
    // echo 'No need to change the refresh node. It\'s only at '.$refreshTimeElapsed.' minutes.<br /><br />';

    // Check to see if the post id is already in the xml file - has it already been set?
    $nodeExists = $xml->xpath("//post[@id=".$postID."]");

    //Count the results
    $countNodeExists = count($nodeExists);

    if($countNodeExists > 0) { // If the ID is already in the file

        // echo 'ID already here';

        // get the correct node
        $result = $xml->xpath("//post[@id=".$postID."]/postviews");

        // heres the trick - the first result of xpath, and the node value (stored in [0])
        $result[0][0] = $result[0][0]+1;

    } else { // If the ID isn;'t there, add a new entry in the xml file for the post

        //echo 'ID added';

        $postNode = $xml->addChild('post'); // adding a new <post> to the top level node
        $postNode->addAttribute('id', $postID); // adding a <postid> inside the new <post>
        $postNode->addChild('postviews', 1); // adding a postviews inside the new <post>
    }

    // save the updated document and format it using the DOMDocument class

    //$xml->asXML($xmlFile);
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
    $dom->save($xmlFile);

} // End if ($refreshTimeElapsed > $refreshInterval) {

} // End if logged in or not published

?>
```

Comment: Isn't this due to concurrency? Two (or more) visitors accessing a post and thus both writing to the file? Ending up with half of two (or more) files.

Answer (score 0):

> Every time someone view a post if the post ID isn't in the file it
>   adds a new node or if it exists it updates the current value by 1.

I'm willing to bet this is being caused by multiple simultaneous executions. Are you locking access to that file ? What happens if two people view a post at the same time ?

I think (longer term) that you're going to be better off storing this info in a database or similar. I don't think writing to a common XML file will scale.

Comment: Hi Brian,

would locking the file solve the problem short term.

I think you're right, database storage would be the better way to go, but for the moment the XML file is working ok, apart from the error :-)